# Firefox submits form targetting iframe in new tab

Tags: firefox, iframe, target

I'm implementing the same-old fake-AJAX file upload. **Every suggested solution I could find on StackOverflow did not work:**

1. Setting the `id` attribute the same as the `name` attribute of the `<iframe>`
2. Hardcoding the `<iframe>` tag
3. Generating the `<iframe>` node via JQuery

I am working on the last version (15.01). Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe we should just change our mindset and design ugly user-unfriendly interfaces unless browsers start to ACTUALLY support HTML5 features, which are damn needed for modern web development.

Comment: Link to a page showing the behavior, please?  This works fine when I test it...

Comment: Please see my own accepted answer, the page is already production code and it is part of a restricted area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `src` attribute that was set to `about: none;`. This caused unexpected behavior.